# Specify data type in advance when assigning by reference in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am taking the course Data Manipulation with data.table in R in datacamp by Arun Srinivasan and Matt Dowle

I have the following code where I am using `bikeshare14 0.1.4` and `data.table 1.14.8`:

```
# Libraries
library(data.table)
library(bikeshare14)

# Data sets
batrips <- as.data.table(x = batrips)

# Data manipulation
batrips[,
        `:=` (median_duration = median(duration, na.rm = TRUE)),
        by = .(start_station, end_station)] |>
  _[,`:=` (trip_category = fcase(
    median_duration < 600, "short",
    median_duration >= 600 & median_duration <= 1800, "medium",
    median_duration > 1800, "long",
    default = NA))]
batrips
```

I obtain the following message `There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`. I check the warnings and all of them are similar where this is one of the warnings `Group 11 column 'median_duration': 481.500000 (type 'double') at RHS position 1 truncated (precision lost) when assigning to type 'integer'`

How can I specify using data.table in advance that I want the column `median_duration` to be of type `num` and not of type `int`?

Comment: Could you share a small reproducible example, e.g., `dput(batrips[1:5, ])` (perhaps subsetting columns as well if there are many irrelevant ones) so that we can run your code without installing a data package?

Comment: Not tested, but my guess is that this is an issue because at least the first group has an integer median, but subsequent groups do not, and this discrepancy causes the warnings. You could try simply `median_duration = as.numeric(median(duration, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: `object 'median_duration' not found`, so using a public dataset like `bikeshare14` is a good start but incomplete in this case ... I see, you like have spiral dev here, where you actually assigned that variable alone and then added to the `\`:=\`(...)` block later. Be mindful of that, please!

Comment: @GregorThomas, your comment is correct, I suggest you post as an answer. (The `bikeshare14` package has no deps and is a quick install; from there, I suggest you demo without the 2nd and subsequent assignments within the `\`:=\`` paren-block.)

Comment: Thank you @r2evans for pointing me out the error. I fixed the error in the code related to the statement of the question.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor Thomas. By fixing the error pointed out by r2evans and applying what you mention I was able to obtain the  result that I want. So the question that I posted was effectively answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this is an issue because at least the first group has an integer median, but subsequent groups do not, and this discrepancy causes the warnings.

Which is to say, the issue isn't setting the column type in `data.table`, the issue is the `median` sometimes returns integers and sometimes returns numerics. To enforce type consistency, wrap the `median()` in `as.numeric()`:

```
median_duration = as.numeric(median(duration, na.rm = TRUE))
```